# Date value is not inserting or updating in MySQL Database Prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

When I update my date field in MySql database Prestashop It's not inserting in the table where column type is "Date". 
And when I change the column type to "varchar" , It's calculating the date means If date comes in this format 2016-4-2 then value will be stored "2010". And when I place date manually in the query then it works. Please help me out.

```
if (Tools::getValue('id_abono')) {
print_r($_POST['datetex']);
$dtt= $_POST['datetex'];
$dtr= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $dtt);
Db::getInstance()->execute('Update '._DB_PREFIX_.'lgabonos set date='.$dtr.'        
WHERE id_abonos = '.pSQL(Tools::getValue('id_abono')).'');
$output .= @Module::displayConfirmation($this->l('The credit note has been successfully updated'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('Update '._DB_PREFIX_.'lgabonos set date="'.$dtr.'"        
WHERE id_abonos = '.pSQL(Tools::getValue('id_abono')).'');
```

I think it will solve your problem